# How to use regular expression to locate certain string B after certain string A across multiple lines separeted by "\n"

Tags: java, regex

I have text stored in a string from a pdf file. And there are around 30 lines separated by `"\n"`. And I am using regex in java to locate a substring behind another string. But these two strings are not in the same line.

Ex, text like this:

```
Title
content1
the percentage is 23%
This is a test. Test A
the percentage is 80%
content2
```

I need to get all percentages that are after `"This is a test"`, in this case `80%`.

I was using regex:  `(?<=This is a test.)\\d*\\d\\%`

But seems it's only looking into the line `"This is a test. Test A"`, not anything after that.

I know I can use the split but in real case I might need to split multiple times and that will comprmise the current method sturcture I have right now. Trying to accomplish it using pure regex. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Try this `(This is a test).*\\n*.*\\d{1,2}\%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This is a test[\s\S]*?(\d+%)
```

Try this.Grab the capture or group.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pM9yO9/11

For java use

```
This is a test[\\s\\S]*?(\\d+%)
```

Comment: It works except that the output comes with the "This is a test". Do you think i can get rid of that part purely using regex?

Comment: @CharlieZeng you have to capture the group.Match.group.It will give only percentage.group(1)

Comment: I am using:  Pattern p=Pattern.compile(regExp); Matcher m = p.matcher(content);    and use m. found() m.group() to get the result. But there is only one match which has the "This is a test." Can you give me more hint, thx.

Comment: @CharlieZeng use `m.group(1)`

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I am new to regex. It took me time to finally understand what group means. But now it's all working. Really appreciate it.